# String within externally saved Qlik Sense expression

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a small issue, so here's a bit of background:

We are developing a Qlik Sense application and we normally write our expressions to an external script. We save these as variables, and then evaluate the variables in the application. The advantage of this is a) we can use better version control with GIT, and b) we can separate the queries from the application if we ever need to change platforms in future.

My Problem:

I have come across a situation where we need to concat a string to the result of an expression, which can be done easily in the application, but when you save the expression to an external file the single quotes around the expression interfere with the single quotes around the string.

I tried

- using double quotes for the string only, but qlik doesn't evaluate it correctly.
- same goes for the expression using double quotes only.
- escaping the single quote inside the expression, eg. "\'" but same story.

What I was thinking of doing next was changing the quote to a rogue character so qlik would ignore it as text, then replacing it with a quote later so qlik would then try to evaluate it.

Example Code:

```
SET variable = 'if(isnull(month),'Month: ' & date(now(), 'MMM-YYYY'),'Month: ' & only({$<year={2016}, month={6}>}month)';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further research I found that Qlik has its own way of escaping characters without using the "\" character. I was able to solve this issue by escaping the inner single quotes like this:

```
SET variable = 'if(isnull(month),''Month: '' & date(now(), ''MMM-YYYY''),''Month: '' & only({$<year={2016}, month={6}>}month)';
```

Feels like a pretty silly oversight now, but hopefully this will save someone some time in the future.